# xls get property of XFDL file

Tags: xml, html, xslt, xls, xfdl

I'm converting XFDL to HTML and I've got a problem. In structure:

```
<XFDL>
    <globalpage sid="global">
        <global sid="global">
            <formid>
                ...
            </formid>
        </global>
    </globalpage>
    <page sid="PAGE1">
        //other nodes
       <button sid="Save_BUTTON">
           <pecs:short_cut xfdl:compute="toggle(global.global.keypress, '', 'F2') == '1' ? (set('activated','on')) : ''"/>
           <type>save</type>
           <bgcolor>
               <ae>190</ae>
               <ae>0</ae>
               <ae>76</ae>
           </bgcolor>
           <justify>center</justify>
        </button>
   </page>
</XFDL>
```

How I can get property pecs:short_cut xfdl:compute ?

Comment: From what context?

Comment: That's css property for button.Or what do you mean? @michael.hor257k

Comment: I mean where are you in your XSLT when you need this. What is your [context node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#dt-current-node). Please see: [mcve]

Comment: @michael.hor257k edited the example

Comment: Your example is still incomplete (the `pecs` and `xfdl` prefixes are undefined) - **and** you still didn't give us your context.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jt97aymmxvz2aza/25.xfdl?dl=0 - that's full document. Maybe it helps, thanks. @michael.hor257k

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask